# Unexpected Token Error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

package com.hello_world.helloworld;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.util.log;


public class HelloWorld extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG - "My Message";
```

Another error it says is that Private field 'TAG' is never used. I am unsure why i am getting these errors and I need help solving them. I tried to solve this issue with some other solutions but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I believe there is a syntax error. It should probably be:

```
private static final String TAG = "My Message";
```

Secondly, the error just means that this line of code is never used. To solve it, just delete that line of code. (Alternately, you could use it somewhere like `Log.i(TAG, "Application Running");` )